# How to update User object by pushing a schema ref to a User's array field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My `user` schema has an array of `Notifcation` objects. I would like to find a user by their email and then update the `user's` notifications field by adding a new `notification` object. The code I have right now doesn't return an error but it also doesn't update the `user's` notification field with new notification.

```
        var notification = { type: data.notification_type, from: socket.request.user._id };
        notification = new Notification(notification);

        User.update({ email: data.to }, { $push: { notifications: notification } }, function(err, model) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
        });
```

#### User Schema

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your first name']
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your last name']
    },
    organization: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        required: 'Please fill in an organization name'
    },
    position: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        required: 'Please fill in the title of your position'
    },
    displayName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your email'],
        match: [/.+\@.+\..+/, 'Please fill a valid email address']
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: 'testing error message',
        required: 'Please fill in a username',
        trim: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyPassword, 'Password should be longer']
    },
    salt: {
        type: String
    },
    provider: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Provider is required'
    },
    providerData: {},
    additionalProvidersData: {},
    roles: {
        type: [{
            type: String,
            enum: ['user', 'admin']
        }],
        default: ['user']
    },
    updated: {
        type: Date
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    /* For reset password */
    resetPasswordToken: {
        type: String
    },
    resetPasswordExpires: {
        type: Date
    },
    notifications: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Notifcation'
    }]
});
```

Comment: Is `"notifications"` an array of "embedded" data or is it just a "referenced" list of `ObjectId` values only? If the latter, then do you actually intend to store the `Nofication` in it's own collection or not? It all makes a difference to how you actually handle this.

Comment: @NeilLunn Updated with User schema. `ObjectId` for the first question but I'm not sure what you mean by the second question? I'm using the Notification schema simply to outline the notification object, is this not correct to do?

Comment: When you use "ref" it is meant to point to another "Model" where the data will actually be saved. So what I am asking is are you expecting the "new" `Notification` to be saved in another collection. Or do you just not understand what to do and are expecting the data to be embedded objects within the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use findOneAndUpdate instead of just update . first you have to find using your condition and then push your notification .i hope this help's

```
var notification = { type: data.notification_type, from:      socket.request.user._id };
    notification = new Notification(notification);

    User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { email: data.to }, 
        { $push: 
           { notifications: notification }
        }, 
        function(err, model) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: i just check you use object reference in notification (updated question) that does not work with this condition . you can only push in array
notifications: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Notifcation'
    }]